# Unable To MERGE Small Subsets of Data Into Large, Partitioned BigQuery Tables

Tags: google-bigquery

Though I have tested the BigQuery MERGE function on smaller datasets, which work fine, I am unable to MERGE small-ish datasets (~2M rows) into a larger (~250M rows) data/column partitioned table.  I receive no error, just a result message that says, "0 rows affected."  Is this due to quotas, or just not possible?

Comment: No error means the MERGE query succeeded, so "0 rows affected" means the MERGE query didn't find any rows to operate on. You need to revise your MERGE query.

Comment: If I use a subset of both the to-be-merged data and the merge-into data, however, rows are indeed either updated or merged in.  The only difference is the volume of data.

Comment: You can post your query here so others can help identify the issue. If you do not want to share the query here, or you think your query is correct and this is a bug in BigQuery, you can report the issue and someone from BigQuery will investigate, https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list.